# The selected option is not saved in the form, but it stores another option

Tags: php, html, forms

I have three options in the drop down list:

1. Deployed
2. Not Deployed
3. Faulty

When i chose "deployed" ,its saved correctly.
When i chose "Not Deployed" ,its saved with "Faulty"
When I chose "Faulty", its saved with "Faulty"

Can you please help me resolve this issue so that form is saved with the selected option only.
Thanks.

```
</div>
                    </div>
                    <?php if(isset($vehicledetails[0]['v_is_active'])) { ?>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="v_is_active" class="form-label">Machinery Status</label>
                        <select id="v_is_active" name="v_is_active" class="form-control " required="">
                          <option value="">Select Machinery Status</option> 
                          <option <?php echo (isset($vehicledetails) && $vehicledetails[0]['v_is_active']==1) ? 'selected':'' ?> value="1">Deployed</option> 
                          <option <?php echo (isset($vehicledetails) && $vehicledetails[0]['v_is_active']==0) ? 'selected':'' ?> value="0">Not Deployed</option> 
                          <option <?php echo (isset($vehicledetails) && $vehicledetails[0]['v_is_active']==0) ? 'selected':'' ?> value="0">Faulty</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  <?php } ?>
```

Can you please help me resolve this issue so that form is saved with the selected option only.

Comment: two items in the list have same value - how is the server to know what a value of zero represents if it is a valid value for two different states?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have an array of $vehicledetails data like

```
$vehicledetails = array(
        array(
            'v_is_active' => 1
        )
    );
```

So, the problem with your code is that you have repeated the same condition for each of the three options.

As a result, if any of the conditions are met, all options will appear as selected.

The conditions for each option should be updated to reflect the appropriate value from $vehicledetails[0]['v_is_active'].

Furthermore, the values for the "Not Deployed" and "Faulty" options appear to be incorrect, as they both have a value of 0.

Revised Code:

```
<?php if(isset($vehicledetails[0]['v_is_active'])) { ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="v_is_active" class="form-label">Machinery Status</label>
            <select id="v_is_active" name="v_is_active" class="form-control" required="">
                <option value="">Select Machinery Status</option> 
                <option <?php echo ($vehicledetails[0]['v_is_active'] == 1) ? 'selected' : ''; ?> value="1">Deployed</option> 
                <option <?php echo ($vehicledetails[0]['v_is_active'] == 0) ? 'selected' : ''; ?> value="0">Not Deployed</option> 
                <option <?php echo ($vehicledetails[0]['v_is_active'] == 2) ? 'selected' : ''; ?> value="2">Faulty</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code has resolved the issue. Am grateful.

Comment: Glad to know, it helped. Follow for more amazing content. The Twitter account is [Link](https://twitter.com/loveforrobotics).